# One user for all databases?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have been doing a lot of work on my local machine and I currently have 5 instances of Wordpress running using wamp. I am sure the answer is a matter of preference but I want to know if you should create a new user and database for each wordpress site? Here are a few of my names of my directorires that I have locally. wordpress, wordpress-dev, wpsandbox, wpxp, etc..They all have there use and I am actually adding one now which is why I am asking this question.

Currenlty each wordpress install has its own database and user with the same name so moving forward should I stick with this or is one global user assigned to each database best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a production environment you certainly want to have separate users to better manage permissions, minimize damage if one of the user credentials is compromised, etc.

In a development environment on your local computer I doubt it matters much, one user for all your databases is more convenient. I find myself doing that at times.

However one could make the argument that a developer should be using *best practices* from the get go, even in a development environment. So if your question is "should I be employing good security measure even in my local development environment" I think the answer is always "yes, unless you have a compelling reason not to."

Comment: Thank for your input. I agree it is best to follow best practices but for simplicity I will now use a single user for all databases.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a localmachine where you have access, and only you. Then having 1 user for all databases should not be a problem.

Yes this is down to personal preference; but I see it as, in a live production web service. You should get into the practice of having 1 user with only the rights that it needs.

*Example:*

Database Name: Testing

Database Name: Another

*Users:*

Root -- Connect to append changes to the structure of the actual table/schema.

User1 -- Select, Insert, Delete and other necessary functions specific to `Testing`

User2  -- Same as the above, but specific to `Another`

Comment: I have now created a user "Admin" which will control all databases. Thanks